# Using wpdb without loading all plug-ins via wp-load.php

Tags: plugins, ajax, wpdb, wp-load.php

I'm trying to **prevent WP from loading all plug-ins** when including wp-load.php, since I don't really need them nor the usual WP actions/filters. All I need is the WPDB class to query the database easily.

I've only found [an (old) solution](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/01/10/preventing-wordpress-plugins-from-loading/) that involves defining WP_INSTALLING to trick WP into not loading plug-ins, but I'm not sure if it still works on current versions and/or if there's a better way.

(Background: I'm trying to optimize a simple autocomplete PHP script that serves JSON results via AJAX by doing some simple queries after initializing $wpdb via wp-load.php)

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 3.4+ Method:
Just define this
`define( 'SHORTINIT', true );`
before you call wp-load.php

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is heavy out-of-the-box. If you only need the database, you'd be **so much** better off using `mysqli` or `PDO` and just connecting directly.

Not to mention (in my opinion) `PDO` beats hell out of `wpdb` anyway, win win.

> the idea is to make use of the DB defines in wp-config.php without needing to store the username/password somewhere else

Create `wp-config-db.php` with just your database constants, then swap them out in `wp-config.php` for `require './wp-config-db.php';`

Now you can just load `wp-config-db.php` in your handler and hey presto.

Comment: That could work, but the idea is to make use of the DB defines in wp-config.php without needing to store the username/password somewhere else, and I cannot include just wp-config.php: it also includes wp-settings.php with WP functions that wouldn't work.

I could normally add an if() to skip wp-settings in wp-config.php, but I don't have much control over wp-config.php on this particular production instance so I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: See my revision :)